# 2 Console Apps started for debugging but the first app started can't reach breakpoints

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

I have two .net 6.0 console apps, one Api and one Ui app.
Both are started  separetly with debugging enabled. But only the last one started
can reach the breakpoints.
The message when i hover over the breakpoint is "Didn't find the asssociated module for the breakpoint".

Has anyone an idea how i can change this?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED : I had to manually "Attach to process .." under Run menu and thenselect the process where the module was not found.

Now it works even after an restart of the ide.